# How do you find the right rhetorical device to describe the towering trees in a primeval forest?

Tags: description

During my trip, I visited the primitive forest and was deeply shocked by the scenery in the forest: the trees were strong and straight, and the environment was full of vitality and quiet. Therefore, I wanted to describe the primitive forest with words and highlight the characteristics of the trees.

I considered comparing it to **a poplar tree in a frontier area**, but because the metaphor is *too common* and poplar trees grow sparsely, not as *compact* as the trees in a virgin forest.

I also considered comparing it to **the harp**, but the elegant character of the harp does not match *the rough and primitive character* of the tree. And since harps are not common, they may not be descriptive.

Some friends suggested that I compare it to **a giant in the mountain**, but I still felt that it did not match the characteristics of *the large number of trees*.

To sum up, I hope to find a description of the trees I see in an appropriate way, and I hope you can give me some guidance, if you can use metaphors, anthropomorphism, or exaggerated rhetoric, it would be better. Thank you.

Comment: What's wrong with your very first sentence?  I'd suggest changing *shocked* to *moved* but that's just my opinion.

Comment: Agree with the above comment. The reason your opening paragraph works and the others don't is because you are telling me how you *feel* and describing what is *unique*.... In the later descriptions you're comparing to LESSER ORDINARY objects and giving no awe – it feels like a downgrade.